# What is the best solution for filtering results in Spring Data JPA with many properties?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, repository, spring-data-jpa, querydsl

I have a case here for a products Table, That needs to be filtered by user input like Category, color, size, price range and many more.

I'm using Spring Data JPA and happy with its derived query from method name and when I'm forced to I just use the @query option for more complex queries like joins and ...

But for the Filter method that I need,  I'm afraid I have to write something like this

> ```
> public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product, Long> {
>    //..... other methods
>
> Page<Product> findByCategoriesContainingAndSalepriceBetween(List<Category> categories, Float minprice, Float maxprice, PageRequest pagerequest);
>
> Page<Product> findByCategoriesContaining(List<Category> categories, PageRequest pagerequest);
>
> Page<Product> findByCategoriesContainingAndSizeIn(List<Category> categories,Int[] sizes, PageRequest pagerequest);
>
> Page<Product> findByCategoriesContainingAndSizeInAndSalepriceBetween(List<Category> categories,Float minprice, Float maxprice, PageRequest pagerequest);
> ```
>
> }

#### it seems adding some other fields will force me to write so many different combinations

so I've looked at QueryDsl and Specification but they seem so much of extra code, could you put me on the right path??

Comment: after noticing my question here after a year, I'm now an addict to QueryDsl and do so many great stuff with it. I just fell in love guys, try it and you'll know what I mean.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would disagree that QueryDSL results in a lot of extra code. Here's some test code I have for QueryDSL:

Repository Definition:

```
public interface UserRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<User, Long>, QueryDslPredicateExecutor<User> {

    public User findOne(Predicate predicate);

    public List<User> findAll(Predicate predicate);
}
```

Test Code based on various attributes and combinations thereof:

```
 @Test
    public void testFindByEmailAddress() {
        User user = repository.findOne(QUser.user.emailAddress.eq("jack@hamilton.net"));
        Assert.assertNotNull(user);
        Assert.assertEquals("Jack", user.getForename());
        Assert.assertEquals("Hamilton", user.getSurname());
    }

    @Test
    public void testFindByGender() {
        List<User> users = repository.findAll(QUser.user.gender.eq(Gender.M));
        Assert.assertEquals(4, users.size());

        users = repository.findAll(QUser.user.gender.eq(Gender.F));
        Assert.assertEquals(2, users.size());
    }

    @Test
    public void testFindByCity() {

        List<User> users = repository.findAll(QUser.user.address.town.eq("Edinburgh"));
        Assert.assertEquals(2, users.size());

        users = repository.findAll(QUser.user.address.town.eq("Stirling"));
        Assert.assertEquals(1, users.size());
    }

    @Test
    public void testFindByGenderAndCity() {
        List<User> users = repository.findAll(QUser.user.address.town.eq("Glasgow").and(QUser.user.gender.eq(Gender.M)));
        Assert.assertEquals(2, users.size());

        users = repository.findAll(QUser.user.address.town.eq("Glasgow").and(QUser.user.gender.eq(Gender.F)));
        Assert.assertEquals(1, users.size());
    }
```

Comment: I agree your code seems very nice, but what about some combinations like my case? have you something like that in your codes to show off?

Comment: testFindByGenderAndCity() in the example? I can pass any number of params using the 'and' operator without adding any more code to the repository.

Comment: for example how you're gonna do a join here and or group results in the way you've written your code? you can't just connect them all with `and`

Comment: between(...), in(...), and(...), http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/2.2.3/apidocs/com/mysema/query/types/expr/BooleanExpression.html

Comment: you answer made me try QueryDsl and yes it is a great tool, it seems to solve most of my problems but you answer is still missing the point about how to group results  or more complex things, I understood JPA implementation of querydsl is working only with BooleanExpressions of querydsl, and I'm not going to be able to do a group by like this, Is that right??

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java Spring framework, you can use the Specifications API where they have provided higher level abstraction of joins. You can refer to the answer in this thread.
[Spring boot Dynamic Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39167189/spring-boot-dynamic-query)